# Unable to open Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

Was working with PyQt5 and suddenly Anaconda crashed and now I am unable to open Anaconda Navigator or Spyder. I was using Anaconda3. I installed PyQt5 using pip and in the Anaconda prompt itself.
This is the error I am getting.

```
 File "C:\Users\Z0041DYR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Z0041DYR\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\Z0041DYR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\Z0041DYR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\Z0041DYR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Comment: @Treton I did a complete uninstall of anaconda and installed it again. Still I am unable to open it.

Comment: This seems to be what you already tried, but it's all I could find.  https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola/issues/971 & https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8223

Comment: @Treton tried that, it's coming that the requirement is satisfied.
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in c:\users\z0041dyr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (5.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5_sip<13,>=4.19.19 in c:\users\z0041dyr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyqt5) (12.7.0)

Comment: @TasheerHussain install pyqt5 from conda: `conda install -c anaconda pyqt`

Comment: @eyllanesc Done that, still facing the same issue.

Comment: @TasheerHussain 1) Do you still have the same error message? 2) How did you install spyder?

Comment: Yes I still have the same issue. Spyder came with Anaconda. @eyllanesc

Comment: Do not ask if it is the same issue but if it is the same error message.

Comment: @eyllanesc It still gives the same error message

Comment: @eyllanesc I reinstalled Anaconda and then again executed that command and it worked. Thanks Alot !